# Formation en alternance

Tags: sens, travail

Qu'est-ce exactement qu'une « formation en alternance » ?

C'est la même chose que ce qu'on désigne en anglais par « apprenticeship » ?

Answer (score 4):

*Emploi en alternance*, je ne connais pas.  *Formation en alternance* est un type de formation comprenant des cours dans une école et une partie pratique en entreprise.

Comment: Tu as raison, ma faute, je voudrais dire Formation en alternance. Merci dans tous le cas.

Answer (score 2):

En recherchant *emploi en alternance* sur Google, on trouve des sites ([exemple](http://www.manpower.fr/candidats/trouver-un-emploi/quel-contrat-pour-vous/alternance)) qui semblent indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un emploi en formation.

À noter qu'en Suisse, je n'ai pas souvent entendu le terme *emploi / [formation en alternance](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_par_alternance)*. On parle plutôt de système de *formation duale* et pour une personne, on parle de son *apprentissage*.

Je pense donc que le terme *emploi en alternance* désigne bien en anglais un *apprenticeship*.